# Altium net has only one pin in hierarchical design despite port connection

Tags: pcb-design, altium

I am working on a multi channel hierarchical design in Altium 19 and getting an error 'net has only one pin' for all signals contained in buses routed between two sheets.

Below is my top level schematic. I've circled the bus SENSE as an example to trace.

[image]

In the MCU sheet below, I connect the SENSE[1..17] port to a bus with label 'SENSE[1..17]', then break out individual signals in the bus to pins on the MCU.

[image]

In the Switches sheet, I have duplicated sheets for two different types of switches, and I group their SENSE nets together into one large bus going to a port as shown below.
[image]

I've seen it suggested in other posts that net identifier scope set to 'global' will fix the issue, however I don't see why the error is occurring at all since I've followed the rules and used ports to make connections between sheets.

Below are the errors, for reference:

[image]

Comment: This question might be better directed to the Altium forums.

Comment: do you know Altium has an open forum ?

Comment: Perhaps I am mistaken but I think you need to break out the bus into its individual nets using a "Bus Entry" for each signal.

Answer (score 2):

You did repeat the sheets but not the sheet entries.

`Repeat(COUT, 1,5)`

By this you have the components from this sheet five times. When you name the Sheet entry SENSE the SENSE port of all five sheets are connected to the identical net (sometimes this is intended).

Leave the port name of the sub sheet named `SENSE` but on the sheet symbol with the repeat statement you need the call it `REPEAT(SENSE)`. You need to name the net between the repeated sheet port and the bus with a net label called `SENSE`.

See [Altium Doku](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/multi-sheet-and-multi-channel-design-ad?version=18.1) and this [Picture](https://www.altium.com/documentation/sites/default/files/resize/wiki_attachments/296859/MultiChannel_Multiple-260x235.png) in chapter "Creating a Multi-Channel Design" Bus "Headphone[1,8]"